# populating a list of checkboxes from a database, some variables are unique

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a list of places to visit in the boat tours I organise, the tour locations of which can change occasionally, including the price for each. So I have found a way to populate the list of possible locations and accommodation and other possible costs, so that I can quickly compute the total costs for each custom tour, with a simple checkbox (the checkbox for the customer to decide which places to visit or stay at). The entrance fees and hotel etc costs for most places are per person, but some are per boat, such as the case of beer, or a van transfer of the group to their final destination. In such cases the charge for each location ($priceofspot) would not be multiplied by the number of people in the group ($ppl). I guess this should be inserted in some sort of While loop or something? I have no idea which direction to go to resolve this, even some basic pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
if(in_array($place,$spotsarray)) {
    print "<input name='spots[]' value='".$place."' type='checkbox' checked='checked' />&nbsp;".$place." - ".$priceofspot."<br>";    
    if (($place='Case of beer') OR ($place='Van Transfer Sibaltan'))
    {$totalspotcost=$totalspotcost+$priceofspot;}
    else {$totalspotcost=$totalspotcost+($priceofspot*$ppl);}
}
else print "<input name='spots[]' value='".$place."' type='checkbox' />&nbsp;".$place." - ".$priceofspot."<br>";
```

Comment: `if (($place='Case of beer')` - that's not a comparison, that's an assignment.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Can you provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you want to do a checkbox list and calculate the total. You can do this with switch if you want to.

```
  <?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($places_selected); $i++){
  if(array_key_exists($places_selected[$i], $ppl_multiplie_list){
    // Multiplie people normally
    $people = $ppl_count;
    // Given input from user.
  }
  else{
    // People = 1
    $people = 1;
  }
    switch($places_selected[$i]){
      case 'Case of beer':
      $total_price = $total_price + $spot_price['Case of beer'] * $people;
      // Or instead of $spot_price array just enter a price.
      break;
  }
}
echo 'Your total is :' . $total_price;
```

Comment: Cool, will try it out, but for the boatman I'd also like to show the total for each individual item, and THEN calculate the total afterwards. So that the boatman could see the total for each particular item (which is usually multiplied by the number of people on the tour, with the exception of some items). Will the above accomplish that? Will check it out and thank you.

Comment: To check price per person do $total_price / $people

Comment: Also you can calculate price for every individual item in js (As you said). If you want to see that solution just let me know !

Comment: not interested in price per person but price per item, where most items are per person charge while a few are price per boat. Ie- accommodation, food and entrance fees are charged per person, but for each boat they can request a case of beer, or surfboard, or bottle of wine etc. After I get the totals for each item, then I'd like to calculate the total costs of everything, which should be easy enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand the response from kyc and doesn't include the checkboxes etc, so I decided a more simple solution would be just to create different tables:

1. one where the total price per spot multiplies by the number of people (most of the spots);
2. one where the total price per spot is just the price per spot (since the cost is per boat, such as one complimentary case of beer, not per person);
3. and one where the total price per spot multiplies by the number of days of the tour, such as if they want to rent a kayak or wakeboard etc.